# Using React's Hooks useReducer, the state is not "single source of truth"? How does the App or Sibling get the state of other components?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-reducer

I tried the [sample code of useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer):

```
const initialState = { count: 0 };

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return { count: state.count + 1 };
    case "decrement":
      return { count: state.count - 1 };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

export default function Counter() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  // ...
```

and instantiated 3 Counters in the App.
Sample on: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-morse-c017r

So it seems the state is local to each Counter component, and is not the "single source of truth" like on Redux?  If the App wants to get the value of all counters, or one Counter wants to get the value of another Counter, how would that be done?

Comment: you can use context API for creating single source of truth.

Comment: @AmitChauhan is there official docs on how that's done?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: also this one is really useful for creating and using context: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

Comment: @AmitChauhan is this one good? https://www.sitepoint.com/replace-redux-react-hooks-context-api/

Comment: You can dispatch to an event bus, minimal overhead, flexible placement. [Stackblitz](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-glitter-2n4hw)

Answer (score 1):

I made changes in your codesandbox and used context to make your counter as single source of truth like redux.

```
import React from "react";
const CountStateContext = React.createContext();
const CountDispatchContext = React.createContext();
function countReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment": {
      return { count: state.count + 1 };
    }
    case "decrement": {
      return { count: state.count - 1 };
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`);
    }
  }
}
function CountProvider({ children }) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(countReducer, { count: 0 });
  return (
    <CountStateContext.Provider value={state}>
      <CountDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
        {children}
      </CountDispatchContext.Provider>
    </CountStateContext.Provider>
  );
}
function useCountState() {
  const context = React.useContext(CountStateContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useCountState must be used within a CountProvider");
  }
  return context;
}
function useCountDispatch() {
  const context = React.useContext(CountDispatchContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    throw new Error("useCountDispatch must be used within a CountProvider");
  }
  return context;
}
export { CountProvider, useCountState, useCountDispatch };
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-wildflower-ihvjj

Comment: oh, now, we do want to keep the count for Noodle and Drink independent... so even thought we want "single source of truth", we want to keep the count independent of each other... and want App to be able to access them, and want each counter be able to access other counts... does that involve making 6 actions, and a lot of repeated code?

Comment: I have updated same codesandbox with you can pass name to get and set counter value.

Comment: so it looks like when the Component is written, it has to be ready for multiple counters and know how to handle it.  We can't just write a Counter component that is standalone that doesn't need to worry it has to have a `name`, and use something like `<Counter mapDataToStoreProperty="countNoodle" />` and be done with it

Comment: the original concern of using MVC was not to write a large amount of imperative code... but with React it looks like simple things are done with a large amount of code